# How can I make the cover photos of movies even in height in this CSS Grid layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid layout which displays some cover photos of movies. How can I make the covers to be the same size in heiit to some extent by applying a `width: 500px` to the `img` element but then on the mobile view the covers look a little bit too stretched in height.

I'm not looking for a specific fixed height value like above `500px` but I want all the cover to be the same height. It's okay if the images reduce themselves a bit as  I shrink the window but I want them to be all the same height.

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f6f2e7;
}

.movies {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.item-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateZ(-40px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.item-inner:hover {
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .movies {
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  .movies {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn-grid.css">
  <title>Movies Grid</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item-1 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="http://smashinghub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Use-AIDA-Formula.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-2 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://images.moviesanywhere.com/6305a9e8ed76d5fa485ac16637655cf7/bcc68be4-eede-409b-a63d-e179b28d19b4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-3 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/12230/movieposter/101-dalmatians-5a529ef29b36c.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-4 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PWF-yAEyL._AC_SL1100_.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the image below the covers don't fill their cell height, setting height: 100% on the image doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and define an explicit `height` for grid-items in a [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid). This way you can keep `height: 100%` on the `<img>` and it will fill 100% of the grid items height. Where each image in the grid has equal height.

I gave `.item-inner` a height of `30rem` to define an explicit height for each grid-item and this value could be modified to your liking. There are [relative length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) units in CSS and this where the `rem` unit comes into play. The value of `rem` is relative to font-size of the root element. You could also just use a `px` value for the height of `.item-inner` as well.

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f6f2e7;
}

.movies {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.grid-item img {
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30rem; /* 480px equivalent */
  transform: translateZ(-40px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.item-inner:hover {
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .movies {
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  .movies {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn-grid.css">
  <title>Movies Grid</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item-1 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="http://smashinghub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Use-AIDA-Formula.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-2 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://images.moviesanywhere.com/6305a9e8ed76d5fa485ac16637655cf7/bcc68be4-eede-409b-a63d-e179b28d19b4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-3 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/12230/movieposter/101-dalmatians-5a529ef29b36c.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-4 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PWF-yAEyL._AC_SL1100_.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ZoltanKing Let me know if this helps solve your problem.

Comment: That works fine but what is that `.item-inner` sorcery? I never set height in rem.

Comment: @ZoltanKing Ok glad it's working for you. You could forego using `rem` (Font size relative to the root element) and go for a `px` value the same way. If the default font-size on the "root elemet" ie `<html>` is 16px then 1rem = 16px. I updated my answer with a little more explanation.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this helps i did width and height 30%

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f6f2e7;
}

.movies {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-container {
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  display: block;
}

.item-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateZ(-40px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.item-inner:hover {
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .movies {
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  .movies {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn-grid.css">
  <title>Movies Grid</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item-1 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="http://smashinghub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Use-AIDA-Formula.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-2 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://images.moviesanywhere.com/6305a9e8ed76d5fa485ac16637655cf7/bcc68be4-eede-409b-a63d-e179b28d19b4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-3 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/12230/movieposter/101-dalmatians-5a529ef29b36c.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-4 grid-item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PWF-yAEyL._AC_SL1100_.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. It didn't. Now there is just one cover shown on the desktop view instead of three per row.